# Loading pre-trained DNN model using OpenVINO with Go & GoCV - symbol lookup error

Tags: linux, opencv, go, visual-studio-code, openvino

I have installed, and verified installation of **OpenVINO** by following instructions at this link: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html

Editor and Technologies that I am using are: **Visual Studio Code**, **Go Programming Language** and **AWS Lambda**

I am trying to load a pre-trained Deep Learning model and its configuration: **frozen_inference_graph.bin**, **frozen_inference_graph.xml**

Here is the code for it:

```
            net := gocv.ReadNet(localModelPath, localModelConfigPath)
            if net.Empty() {
                glog.Errorf("Error occurred while trying to read DNN model and its configuration from %v. Error message - %v", localModelPath, err)
                return err
            }

            defer net.Close()
            net.SetPreferableBackend(gocv.NetBackendDefault)
            net.SetPreferableTarget(gocv.NetTargetCPU)
```

Whenever I try to debug the program, after trying to execute **gocv.ReadNet** function I get the following error message:

```
/home/jovana/go/src/pipeline/lambda/inferenceLambda/__debug_bin: symbol lookup error: /home/jovana/go/src/pipeline/lambda/inferenceLambda/__debug_bin: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3dnn14dnn4_v201901227readNetERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES9_S9_
```

Note that **go/src/pipeline/lambda/inferenceLambda** is path to the main.go script I am trying to debug.

When I try just to run **main.go** script I get:

```
/tmp/go-build091433297/b001/exe/main: symbol lookup error: /tmp/go-build091433297/b001/exe/main: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3dnn14dnn4_v201901227readNetERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES9_S9_
```

I honestly have no idea what this message means and where to start fixing it. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Also I got the same problem in Docker container of Ubuntu18.04, Ubuntu16.04, CPU && GPU.